# Why does unicode-math require packages twice?

Tags: math-mode, packages, unicode-math

At the beginning of `unicode-math-xetex.sty` and `unicode-math-luatex.sty`, I found

```tex
\RequirePackage{xparse,l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__um_after_package:nNn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \AtBeginDocument
      {
        \cs_new_protected:Npn #2 {#3}
        \@ifpackageloaded {#1} {#2} {}
      }
  }
\RequirePackage{xparse,l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

Is this a special trick?

Comment: looks like a (harmless) mistake, should be fixed though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good news to me. I've been thinking hard about it for a week, trapped in self-doubt.

Comment: the lines got duplicated here https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/a1e27073bd0268c2981bba3f32d1122c4c18600c#diff-51562d1d28d3b8cd60ecbf218c34744f4f97b528969dc13b4094d429490f05d7

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/603

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered in the comments.